# Find out when session was changed

Tags: php

I need to know when there were (timestamp) last changes has been made to current session file, for example, if user was *logged in* and his data was saved to session. 
How can I get this?

Comment: This depends on how the session is stored.  If you're using the default method (file based), you can check the mtime of the session file.

Comment: But session_save_path() return empty string. Why?

Comment: Create a class that deals with sessions and every time you do something (read/delete/update), have the class set the timestamp. Easy, portable, works with every possible session storage mechanism. Did I mention easy?

Comment: @N.B. Yes, in-fact you did. Twice.  To be honest though, tracking sessions if far less useful than tracking authenticated user activity.  Sessions can be reset and disassociated at the user's whim.